# "Partition" without the disjoint condition

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

A partition of a set $A$ is defined as a set of pairwise disjoint sets whose union is $A$.

I'm interested in a related concept, where for a set $A$ you have $Q = \{A_1 \ldots A_n\}$ such that union of all $A_i$ is $A$ but $A_i$ needn't be pairwise disjoint.

I'm looking for standard term for this concept so I can look up further literature on it. The term will read as "$Q$ is the superpartition for $A$", with superpartition being replaced by the actual term.

Comment: "set of sets whose union is $A$".

Comment: Do not, absolutely do not, use “superpartition”. That implies a partition that contains another partition. It is called a “cover by subsets”.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps

> cover (or covering)

For example, ["open cover"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_(topology)) is used in topology (not to be confused with [covering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space) as a projection in topology) and the term ["covering system"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_system) in elementary number theory. I don't think it's standard in a purely elementary set theory context, but it's already effectively used this way in two places in math so it shouldn't be too great a stretch to generalize.

Comment: Perfect. "set cover" seems to be in common use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem

Comment: Ah. I guess it's more standard than I thought.

Comment: I would dare to go as far as to say it is not just common, but canonical.  I can’t imagine any other term being used here instead of “cover” or “covering”.